# Promise on addAssociation is resolved with a stale version of the source

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a versioning schema that versions `object` entries in a `object_version` table

```
const Object = sequelize.define('object', {})

const ObjectVersion = sequelize.define('object_version', {
    title: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
})

Object.hasMany(ObjectVersion, { as: 'versions' })
```

Using [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/), i have a put route where an existing `object` entry can be updated, in this simple example by setting a new `title`, e.g. by sending a PUT request with a body of `{"title":"new title"}`

```
app.put('object/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10)

    Object.findOne({
        where: { id },
        include: [ Object.associations.versions ]
    }).then(object => {
            const newVersion = ObjectVersion.build(req.body, { objectId: id })
            Object.addVersion(newVersion).then(object => {
                // shouldn't this instance have all versions, including the new one?
                // do i need to `findOne` again to get them?
                console.log(object.toJSON().versions)
                res.send(object)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

When using the `addVersion` method that is created on my Object model by associating it to the ObjectVersion model via `hasMany`, the returned promise is resolved with an object instance.

The problem is that i want to return the objects JSON in the response, but the object instance the promise is resolved with does not contain the version that was just added.

To me, this looks like an oversight. It should not be necessary to perform another query. When the promise for the `addXyz` operation is resolved, the new association is already saved in the database so it should be possible to resolve the promise with an updated version of the object.

Maybe i'm going at this the wrong way or missed an easier way to perform an update operation that adds new associations. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an interesting talk on Slack i realised that the `addAssociation`, `addAssociations` and `setAssociations` methods on model instances connect existing rows in the db with the target.

In my example, the `addVersion` method connects an existing `object_version` row with the current `version` instance and can **not** be used to insert a new row into the database.

I've opened a PR to sequelize trying to clarify this in the docs as i skipped right over this. An example that works might look like this:

```
app.put('object/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10)

    Object.findOne({
        where: { id },
        include: [ Object.associations.versions ]
    }).then(object => {
        object.createVersion(req.body).then(version => {
            object.versions.push(version)
            res.send(object)
        })
    })
})
```